# How to force all request to come from my website to avoid spoofing in RoR 3.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url-rewriting, spoofing, rack-rewrite

my site just got spoof.

I'm using RoR 3.2.11 and I installed the rack-rewrite gem.

I created the /middleware dir inside /app and I created a .rb file inside.

Now, how should I write the rule to only allow requests coming from my page?

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `site got spoof`?

Comment: someone took my data and it is using it on their website @JasdeepSingh

Comment: So how exactly is the `rack-rewrite` gem going to help you here?

Comment: Do you mean that someone's linking in content that's hosted on your site? Or have they made a copy?

Comment: I want to force all request to come from my website @JasdeepSingh

Comment: they made a copy using http requests @tadman

Answer (score 3):

If someone's making a copy of your site using HTTP scraping there's usually not much you can do other than make their life difficult and be annoying.

You'll need to consider that anything you do to make it more difficult for another site to clone yours will make it *very* difficult for ordinary readers. Force registration? You'll lose visitors. Encrypt page and require JavaScript? You'll lose readers.

I'd suggest blocking the IPs of the robots you don't like, filing a report with their ISP about copyright infringement, and if things are really bad, engage a lawyer.

Comment: @content01 - Tadman put it nicely here, There's not much you can do except making the life of scrapers a little difficult. The best option would be to identify what IP's these bots/scrapers are using and then block access to them.

Comment: You could also selectively mangle the output so it looks okay but is broken.